# Laravel 7.1 authentication issue

Tags: laravel

on my project i run the following command for auth in laravel 7.1:

```
$ composer require laravel/ui
$ php artisan ui vue --auth
```

while I try to access to my project 
`127.0.0.1:8000/login`

I got login page without any template

Comment: What webserver do you use?

Comment: **Apache server**

Comment: Is `127.0.0.1:8000` the root of the project?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto yes

Comment: Do you mean this is a **blank page**? If yes, try activating `error_reporting`. You can get information from there.

Comment: Did you also run `npm install && npm run dev` after `php artisan ui vue --auth`?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto is not a blank page . it was page without any css effect

Comment: @mdexp I forget to run it Thank you very much

Comment: @mdexp I think about it. Also `APP_URL`. Please answer in the answer box :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `laravel/ui` package with the Vue scaffold you also need to run:

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

to install the js dependencies and compile the Vue assets correctly.